# Why isn't hbm2ddl.import_files working in hibernate4-maven-plugin (Hibernate 4.3.6)?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml, hbm2ddl

I have the following persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="blah" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="myfile.sql"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property isn't working. Doesn't seem to matter where I put myfile.sql or prepend with a slash or even wildcards, classpath etc. (clutching at straws) - it never finds it and the log output doesn't indicate it is even looking for it. The default import.sql is used instead (and works).

Note: Have seen similar questions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392397/hibernate-4-1-2-final-properties-hbm2ddl-import-files-dont-seems-to-work) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835576/hibernate-hbm2ddl-import-files-in-persistence-xml-is-not-working)) but none of the resolutions worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now think this problem is due to using the [hibernate4-maven-plugin](http://juplo.de/hibernate4-maven-plugin/) - it doesn't seem to support all the Hibernate properties.